# How to get BPM value from MPMediaItem class of ios?

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem

I did lots of R&D on BPM but did not get any answer that resolve my issue. I am trying to get BPM value from MPmediaItem class of ios for my iphone application.I have to categorize my app users on the basis of beats per minute of their library songs. So my first task to find out BPM of songs. How can I do that? I got some answers like: 1.using MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute property and 2. Use @"beatsPerMinutes" instaed of MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute property of MPMediaItem class and also some more answer, but didnot get any success. It has always same result for all songs (return null for all songs). Do you have any sample code or logic to get this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add code showing what you've tried so far and where the error occurs.

Comment: trying mediaItem?.beatsPerMinute code to get BPM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int BPM = [[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute]intValue];
```

Comment: Thanks zombie for your response. But its not working for me. I am getting 0 BPM value for all the songs.